# Is there a list of CSS classes for slickgrid?

Tags: css, slickgrid

I'd like to fine tune the appearance of a webpage that uses slickgrid. So I was looking for a list of available CSS classes for slickgrid in order to do that, but was unable to find one.

Is there such a list and can someone point me to it or is the canonical approach for my task a different one?

Comment: Try this hope it works                                                   https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples

Comment: +1 This would be useful. The only way I have found is by looking at the css files that ship with the package and using Firebug to inspect the rendered code.

Comment: Unfortunately slickgrid is generating a lot of the classes dynamically, meaning the pre-existing list of classes will most likely be insufficient to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Slickgrid generates classes to identify rows and columns, but from looking at the output there are no styles attached to these classes:

[image]

You should be able to style rows and columns plus evens, odds, active cells using the classes provided in the [default theme](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick-default-theme.css).

If you want to go deeper and style cells using the generated styles, they seem to go:

```
.slick-row {
  .slick-cell {// default cell style // }
  .10 {//the row number starting at 10 // }
  .r1 (//the column number starting at 1 // }
}
```

So you can style them like so:

```
.slick-row .r0 {
  //style first items in row 
}

.slick-row .10.r0 {
  //style first item in first row 
}

.slick-row div[class^="r"] {
  //style all elements starting with 'r'
}

.slick-row div[class^="r"]:nth-child(3) {
  //style every third row element
}
```

There's many more ways, but I fail to see what kind of styling you need that the default theme doesn't provide. If you need super specific styling, (ie. every seventh row of the fifth column, but not prime numbers) I'd style cells with javascript using the numbered classes.